# Who are Aghories?

Tags: scripture, sects

https://images.app.goo.gl/XfbwNiieY1fSrFMCA

Please give the reference from the scriptures.

Comment: you have to read shiva puruna.. its very difficult to understand hinduism from outside.. because you need to read allthe 18 puranas,mahabarata and ramayana to derive right conclusions.. similarly vedas and upanishads meaning need to got from right persons.. then you can decide why its like that..for you its long way but what i heard from Bannaje govindacharya lecture is on daksha prajapati killing sage rishi gave curse to all the shaivites who consider Lord Shiva as ultimate God.. to take the Aghori life lifestyle,

Comment: by eating flesh like dog, smering ashes from cremation ground.. the curse is still prevelant.Similarly from Lord shiva side they gave curse to those who ignore shiva in worship that they will not be able to control their sexual desire and fall off from spirtual path..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aghoris are Kapalini of Shiva or Maa Durga.
They are kind of Sadhus who live in the nature or love natural kind of life.
Anciently it is told that Aghori were Purushas sent by Shiva on Earth to keep in custody and spread the Dharma.
Maybe true or maybe not.

It is told that Shiva represents the first of the Aghori, when in Rudra form too.

What you have read on Google, not only is false
This is a fake propaganda spreaded by Anti-Hindu people in Bhaarat.

They hate Aghoris because they will never let themselves be tempted by any kind of commodities.

This is not an opinion but the truth as it is.

In Internet you will hardly find any truth around them.

I suggest you to dig into Agamas and Kaula mantra oral initiations by non internet experiences.

Aghori refers to the most closest to Shiva Shakti devotees.

Other Shastras are https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iMJYAGH0qw0

This Shiva Stotram.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WgR2h3r4iRc
महाकाल शिव अघोर मंत्र
इस मंत्र का जाप करने से भोलेनाथ शिवजी आपकी रक्षा करेंगे | कोई भी दृष्ट शक्ति आपके पास नहीं आ सकती

Aghori exist since before the 4 Vedas has been composed.

Most of Sanatana Dharma is still kept orally.

Websites demoting and falsifying the things serve to political campaigns leaded from those people who want to superimpose by force other cults or sects or religions.
Political ploys are making internet a place of fakehoods.

Sources: meeting with Aghori Sadhus in India

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IPLRhTb-eyE

Published on Jan 29, 2019
नागा साधुओं के सन्यास का रहस्य - किस तरह से होती है नागा साधुओं की साधना और तप - Kumbh Mela

The Maha Kumbh takes places once in every 12 years and it was held recently. Here is a sneak peek into what happens inside the Kumbh Mela. It is interesting to see how so many devotees come together and offer their prayers in perfect harmony.The biggest human gathering in the world; the Maha Kumbh took place recently.

You can see Sadhus and Aghori Sadhus as well, participating on that event.

http://www.metaphysics-knowledge.com/customstraditions/facts-about-aghori-sadhus/

Reputable source

https://globalpress.hinduismnow.org/featured/sacred-secrets-aghori-sampradaya/

https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=rudra+rudra+maharudra

This mantra well address to the Aghori aspect of Shiva
"Aghoraya Apayanthaye" etc
Rudra Rudra Maha Rudra

A New source founded

Aghori Mantra, from Aghoris....

ॐ अघोरेभ्योऽथ घोरेभ्यो घोर घोर तरेभ्यः

सर्वेभ्यस् सर्व सर्वेभ्यो नमस्तेऽस्तु रुद्र रूपेभ्यः

oṃ aghorebhyo'tha ghorebhyo ghora ghora tarebhyaḥ

sarvebhyas sarva sarvebhyo namaste'stu rudra rūpebhyaḥ

My salutations to those who are not terrible, to those who are terrible, and to those who are both terrible and not terrible.

Everywhere and always I bow to all Rudra forms.

ॐ नमः शिवाय महादेवाय नीलकंठाय आदि रुद्राय अघोरमंत्राय अघोर रुद्राय अघोर भद्राय सर्वभयहराय मम सर्वकर्यफल प्रदाय हन हनाय ॐ ॐ ॐ ॐ ॐ टं टं टं टं टं घ्रीं घ्रीं घ्रीं घ्रीं घ्रीं हर हराय सर्व अघोररुपाय त्र्यम्बकाय विरुपाक्षाय ॐ हौं हः हीं हः ग्रं ग्रं ग्रं हां हीं हूं हैं हौं हः क्षां क्षीं क्षूं क्षैं क्षौं क्षः ॐ नमः शिवाय अघोरप्रलयप्रचंड रुद्राय अपरिमितवीरविक्रमाय अघोररुद्रमंत्राय सर्वग्रहोच्चाटनाय सर्वजनवशीकरणाय सर्वतोमुख मां रक्ष रक्ष शीघ्रं हूं फट् स्वाहा ।

ॐ क्षां क्षीं क्षूं क्षैं क्षौं क्षः ॐ हां हीं हूं हैं हौं हः स्वर्गमृत्यु पाताल त्रिभुवन सच्चरित देव ग्रहाणां दानव ग्रहाणां ब्रह्मराक्षस ग्रहाणां सर्ववातग्रहाणां सर्ववेतालग्रहाणां शाकिनीग्रहाणां डाकिनीग्रहाणां सर्वभूतग्रहाणां कमिनीग्रहाणां सर्वपिंडग्रहाणां सर्वदेषग्रहाणां सर्वपस्मारग्रहाणां हन हन हन भक्षय भक्षय भक्षय विरूपाक्षाय दह दह दह हूं फट् स्वाहा ॥

oṃ namaḥ śivāya mahādevāya nīlakaṃṭhāya ādi rudrāya aghoramaṃtrāya aghora rudrāya aghora bhadrāya sarvabhayaharāya mama sarvakaryaphala pradāya hana hanāya oṃ oṃ oṃ oṃ oṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ hara harāya sarva aghorarupāya tryambakāya virupākṣāya oṃ hauṃ haḥ hīṃ haḥ graṃ graṃ graṃ hāṃ hīṃ hūṃ haiṃ hauṃ haḥ kṣāṃ kṣīṃ kṣūṃ kṣaiṃ kṣauṃ kṣaḥ oṃ namaḥ śivāya aghorapralayapracaṃḍa rudrāya aparimitavīravikramāya aghorarudramaṃtrāya sarvagrahoccāṭanāya sarvajanavaśīkaraṇāya sarvatomukha māṃ rakṣa rakṣa śīghraṃ hūṃ phaṭ svāhā |

oṃ kṣāṃ kṣīṃ kṣūṃ kṣaiṃ kṣauṃ kṣaḥ oṃ hāṃ hīṃ hūṃ haiṃ hauṃ haḥ svargamṛtyu pātāla tribhuvana saccarita deva grahāṇāṃ dānava grahāṇāṃ brahmarākṣasa grahāṇāṃ sarvavātagrahāṇāṃ sarvavetālagrahāṇāṃ śākinīgrahāṇāṃ ḍākinīgrahāṇāṃ sarvabhūtagrahāṇāṃ kaminīgrahāṇāṃ sarvapiṃḍagrahāṇāṃ sarvadeṣagrahāṇāṃ sarvapasmāragrahāṇāṃ hana hana hana bhakṣaya bhakṣaya bhakṣaya virūpākṣāya daha daha daha hūṃ phaṭ svāhā ||

oṃ namaḥ śivāya

Om, all my salutations to Shiva,

mahādevāya

the highest principal of God,

nīlakaṃtḥāya

you absorb the negativity of the world to keep it from poisoning us.

ādi rudrāya

You are the primal source who relieves our suffering,

aghoramaṃtrāya

coming to us in the form of this awe-inspiring mantra

aghora rudrāya

to remove our fear and suffering.

aghora bhadrāya

By your benign blessing, my fear subsides,

sarvabhayaharāya

along with my distress and anxiety.

mama sarvakaryaphala pradāya

I offer to you the fruits of all my works,

hana hanāya

so that you will destroy my karmic bondage.

oṃ oṃ oṃ oṃ oṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ṭaṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ ghrīṃ

I worship you as the eternal Being, revealing wisdom and removing the blockages of my heart, that divine light will be brought forth.

hara harāya sarva aghorarupāya

Dispell my negativities in all the forms by which you remove fear.

trayambakāya virupākṣāya

You abide in the realm of wisdom and you grant transcendental vision of Divine Mother.

oṃ hauṃ haḥ hīṃ haḥ graṃ graṃ graṃ

Eternal One, guru of all realms, may soul rapture replace personal obsession.

hāṃ hīṃ hūṃ haiṃ hauṃ haḥ

Goddess Durga, grant me wings to ﬂy into divine light.

kṣāṃ kṣīṃ kṣūṃ kṣaiṃ kṣauṃ kṣaḥ

Mother Kali, grant me roots to dive into divine darkness.

oṃ namaḥ śivāya

Om, all my respects to Shiva,

aghorapralayapracaṃḍa rudrāya

furiously dissolve all that causes me fear and, once and for all, remove my suffering.

aparimitaviravīkramāya

Repeatedly, without end, I call to you,

aghorarudramaṃtrāya

who removes suffering and fear through mantra japa,

sarvagrahoccāṭanāya

please drive away the negative inﬂuences of all worlds.

sarvajanavaśīkaraṇāya

You are your own cause as the Supreme Person,

sarvatomukha

omnipresent, with me always.

māṃ rakṣa rakṣa śīghraṃ

You immediately respond and repeatedly protect me;

hūṃ phaṭ svāhā

I offer my puriﬁed self as an oblation into your divine ﬁre, that healing shakti be set free.

oṃ kṣāṃ kṣīṃ kṣūṃ kṣaiṃ kṣauṃ kṣaḥ

Mother Kali, grant me roots to dive into divine darkness.

oṃ hāṃ hīṃ hūṃ haiṃ hauṃ haḥ

Goddess Durga, grant me wings to ﬂy into divine light.

svargamṛtyu patala

You bring freedom from death and rebirth in heaven and hell.

tribhuvana saccarita

Tales of your redemptive grace are known in the three worlds, and penetrate into:

deva grahāṇāṃ

realms of beings of light,

dānava grahāṇāṃ

realms of magical beings,

brahmarākṣasa grahāṇāṃ

realms of fallen brahmins,

sarvavāta grahāṇāṃ

realms of those of the wind,

sarvavetāla grahāṇāṃ

realms of the walking dead (possessed by Vetalas)

śakinī grahāṇāṃ

realms of the primal nature goddesses,

ḍākinīgrahāṇāṃ

realms of the muses, the sky dancers,

sarvabhūtagrahāṇāṃ

realms of all primal, elemental spirits,

kaminīgrahāṇāṃ

realms of the goddesses of desire

sarvapiṃḍagrahāṇāṃ

realms of all those born in wombs

sarvadeṣagrahāṇāṃ

realms of all cultures and countries,

sarvapasmāragrahāṇāṃ

all realms of debilitating ignorance.

hana hana hana

You are the stone cold killer

bhakṣaya bhakṣaya bhakṣaya

who destroys, eliminates, and devours

virupākṣāya

what obstructs the transcendental vision of Divine Mother.

daha daha daha

Burn away my dross.

hūṃ phaṭ svāhā

I offer my puriﬁed self as an oblation into your divine ﬁre, that healing shakti be set free.

There are those who worship the God of the High Heavens.
There are those who worship God in a statue or in an image.
There are those who worship the formless God.
There are those who worship God in their own hearts.
There are those who believe that God is the mind.
The Aghoris worship God in their body or in the body of the others.
Because "I am God", Aham Brahmasmi.

---

Whoever Knows Shiva,
Knows He is Aghori also.

Comment: Ok but what is the reason behind their life style, and why they are different from rishies.

Comment: I already told you that the info that you have are allegations @Dark Knight. If you want to think badly about Aghori and Shiva you are free to think whatever you want. Think they are cannibals, think they are creepy. Maybe you are right. Maybe you are wrong. You can decide eventually to travel India to know this by yourself through a direct experience.

Comment: Whatever your mind is in turmoil and agitation can not connect with reality. "Man changa katorie me Ganga". The mind of the meditator, yogini, is calm like a cup of the Gange river.

Comment: Also. Who told you that they are different from Rishis? #CBI for Phalgar.

Comment: 2  OK thanks of your answer. I don't think badly but what I think about them comes from the movie(Bollywood)

Comment: Ahahahahahahahahahah. So why you asked ? Lol

Comment: I asked about this because I was curious

Comment: Ok I have found something new @Dark Knight :)

Comment: what is the new things

Comment: Read the answer again please.

Comment: OK so you have added something in your answer. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You explicitly asked for Shastras (scriptures) but is hard to find something online. Rely on Agamas but these last are also not easy to find online. Mostly Aghori Sadhus have their books of mantras and shastras. @Dark Knight